# Is there an analogy between mechanical vibrations and electromagnetic waves

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, vibration, electromagnetism

Recent questions about [analogies between mechanical and electrical systems](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41224/transformers-and-systems-with-gears-have-similar-computation-when-having-quantit/42228#42228) and about [electromagnetic waves from a conductor](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/can-a-piece-of-conductor-be-made-invisible-to-radar-by-overdamping) made me wonder whether there is an analogy between the mechanical vibrations of a single degree of freedom (dof) system which are induced by external excitation of the base (see below)

[image]

and the electromagnetic waves from a conductor.

More specifically the [post](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/can-a-piece-of-conductor-be-made-invisible-to-radar-by-overdamping) stated that :

> To my understanding every conductor reemits a bit of electromagnetic waves induced in it by radiation.

I have to admit that I do not know how well does that statement hold, but I am certain that there is at least some truth (so I'll welcome any assessment of the validity of this statement).

In any case, the way I interpreted the above statement was that in both cases it seems to me that there is an external source of "wave-like" energy (notice the quotes), which results in a portion of the energy to absorbed and reemited from the system.

Although, I am somewhat familiar with the mechanical aspect, the rf aspect is uncharted territory for me. If someone can fill in the blanks on the analogy (if such an analogy exists at all), it would help me understand better the electromagnetic aspect by mapping my existing knowledge.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but maybe you should look up the equations for a generic RLC (resistor-inductor-capacitor) circuit.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I know the analogy of the RLC and Damper- mass-spring. However, that is not what I was referring to. I was referring to the reemmiting of rf radiation from a conductor. Probably that is related to the L element. In any case I updated the post, hopefully it is a bit more clear now.